# Firebase RealtimeDB to Google Sheets through AppScript

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database, google-sheets

I am trying to write Firebase RealtimeDB data into a Google Sheets spreadsheet through Google Appscript.

This is what my RealtimeDB looks like: [image: Firebase RealtimeDB]

My goal is 
[image: this]

I have tried the following code snippet:

```
   function writeSheets() {
    var firebaseUrl = "https://<mydatabase>.firebaseio.com/Attendees";
    var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
    var data = base.getData();



    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<mySheet>");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

    var num = 2;
    range = ss.getRange("A"+num+":B"+num+"");
    for(var i in data) {
      var values = [[ data[i].ID, data[i].Name ] ];
      range.setValues(values);
      num += 1;
      range = sheet.getRange("A"+num+":B"+num+"");
      } 

 console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

    }
```

It seems to print empty cells into Google Sheet. Not exactly sure why.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

Console Log :

[20-04-08 20:46:26:102 HKT] TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID' of null
    at writeSheets(Code:13:27)

Comment: Provide sample result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a extra `null` in the data. [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)  it out and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array of objects to a [2D array  and setValues the 2D array](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues):

```js
const data =  [null,{"ID":1001,"Name":"Bob"},{"ID":1069,"Name":"Steve"},{"ID":1420,"Name":"Bill"}];
const out = data.filter(Boolean).map(Object.values);
console.log(out);

/*SetValues the entire array*/
//sheet.getRange(1,1,out.length, out[0].length).setValues(out);
```